# Integration of one vector over another

Tags: arrays, matlab, numerical-integration

I have two vectors of the same size and I want to make a third vector of the same size but values of that third vector are integrated.

I did this in origin and it is quite simple, but I need that in matlab. I will post the **example**:

```
A       B           C(integrated B over A)
0       0           0
0,041   1812,282    37,15178
0,129   2186,023    213,0772
0,25    2318,906    485,62541
0,407   2141,382    835,75801
0,553   1969,284    1135,83663
0,618   1926,069    1262,4356
0,857   2149,071    1749,41483
1,034   2302,972    2143,42064
1,071   2115,559    2225,16346
1,136   2173,948    2364,57244
1,198   2301,871    2503,32283
1,262   975,241     2608,19041
1,343   0           2647,68767
```

Matlab work so far:

I tried

```
C=trapz(B,A)
```

and get the result

```
C =

-2.6481e+03
```

It is ok for the last data point, but I need a vector of data. See example from **origin integration**.

**Question is**: 
How to integrate B over A and get vector of integrated values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C = cumtrapz(A,B)
```

will do.

---

```
data = [
0       0           0
0.041   1812.282    37.15178
0.129   2186.023    213.0772
0.25    2318.906    485.62541
0.407   2141.382    835.75801
0.553   1969.284    1135.83663
0.618   1926.069    1262.4356
0.857   2149.071    1749.41483
1.034   2302.972    2143.42064
1.071   2115.559    2225.16346
1.136   2173.948    2364.57244
1.198   2301.871    2503.32283
1.262   975.241     2608.19041
1.343   0           2647.68767]

A = data(:,1);
B = data(:,2);

C = cumtrapz(A,B)
```

---

returning:

```
C = 
0
37.1517810000000
213.077201000000
485.625405500000
835.758013500000
1135.83663150000
1262.43560400000
1749.41483400000
2143.42063950000
2225.16346300000
2364.57244050000
2503.32282950000
2608.19041350000
2647.68767400000
```